# ROC curve using prebability of predicted class

Tags: r, roc

I need to draw ROC curve using the predicted probabilities for two class problem. The need is to use different cutoff in probabilities to generate the ROC curve.

I am predicting class probabilities using random forest

```
mydata<-read.table(file="out-all-gm-pr-hpcuts-wor-noAl.tr", header=TRUE, sep ="")
mydata$class <- as.factor(mydata$class)
mydata.rf<-randomForest(class ~ ., data=mydata,  importance = TRUE, mtry = 3, ntree = 100, proximity = TRUE )
```

Prediction on test data using above forest

```
mytestdata<-read.table(file="gmsim-craboff.tes",header=TRUE)
testpred<-predict(mydata.rf,mytestdata,type='prob')
```

I now have a data file now with true class label and predicted probabilities for test data. I need to generate ROC curve using different cutoff (say `0.1`, `0.3`, `0.5`, `0.7`, `0.9`) in probabilities. How to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
library(pROC)
roc(mytestdata$class, testpred, plot = TRUE)
```