# How to construct ROC curve in r with a small clinical dataset

Tags: r, curve, roc

I need help with ROC curve in R. My data is not difficult, but I don't know how to get teh ROC curve and AUC. I typed the dataset here if you need to have a look. The cutoff comes from CMMS score (eg. <5/10/20  then the patient have dementia).

```
Table - Relationship of clinical dementia to outcome on the Mini-Mental Status Test

CMMS score    Nondemented Demented
0–5              0           2
6–10             0           1
11–15            3           4
16–20            9           5
21–25            16          3
26–30            18          1
Total            46          16
```

Please let me know any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Generally the ROC curve is used to evaluate the predictive ability of a binary classifier.  Here, I am guessing that the classifying you are trying to do is whether the patient has dementia.  In this case, you would want  your data to look like a list of observations, the CMMS score, an an indicator for whether that specific patient has dementia, rather than the summary statistics you have here.

Comment: You may also want to view this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807310/roc-curve-using-prebability-of-predicted-class as it should answer your basic question of how to construct the ROC curve once your data is correctly formatted

Comment: Close vote: too broad: Coding questions require specification of an algorithm. SO is not here to look up package names or run through Wikipedia pages to come up with a procedure for you. You should put some effort into learning what an ROC curve is and how to build one.

Comment: This is a table of counts from your dataset. Do you have the original observations? If so constructing a ROC curve is trivial with existing packages. If this table is all you have then this is certainly a valid question but should be rephrased ("how to construct a ROC curve from summary data").